# Make a div fill an entire table cell with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, background-color

Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/55cc077/pvu5cmta/

Since css height: 100% only works if the element's parent has an explicitly defined height, this jQuery sets the cell height. Is there a better way to do this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    $('.myTable2 tr').each(function(){
    var H1 = $(this).height(); // Get the row height
    $(this).find('td:first').css({'height': H1 + 'px', 'line-height': H1 + 'px'}); //Set td height to row height
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Are you asking if there's a way to do this with pure CSS, without JS?

Answer (score 1):

CSS only: Set table cell to `position: relative;`

Set div to

```
position: absolute; 
top: 0; 
right: 0; 
bottom: 0; 
left: 0; 
width: 100%;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yxwsjr3v/

Comment: Thanks. That's good although downside is that the text loses vertical alignment. Running the jQuery brings it back.

Comment: Fair point.  I've added another div inside the "grey" div (#3 and #5 on second table only as examples), and set that to `position: absolute; margin: auto; height: 1.5em; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;` and that fixes the centering:

https://jsfiddle.net/yxwsjr3v/1/

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a div inside the td to set the background color? Just set the background color for the td itself like this:

```css
 table, th , td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align:center;
 }

 th {
  background:#abcdef;
 }
 .myTable1, .myTable2 {
  width:20px;
 }
 .gray {
  background:#b0b0b0;
 }
```

```html
<p>mytable1 without jQuery</p>
 <table class="myTable1">
   <tr>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td class="gray">1</td>
    <td>10 20 30 40 50 60</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td class="gray">2</td>
    <td>80</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td class="gray">3</td>
    <td>75</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td class="gray">4</td>
    <td>30</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="gray">5</td>
    <td>21 31 41 51 61 100 200</td>
   </tr>

 </table>
```